# Unity: registering a decorator in a child container

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container

I have the following scenario:

In the base container, I am registering a type.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo,Foo>();
```

In a child container I would like to register a Decorator which wraps whatever the base container uses. So if I have this class:

```
public class FooDecorator: IFoo
{
    public FooDecorator(IFoo foo) {}
}
```

I want to register:

```
childContainer.RegisterType<IFoo,FooDecorator>();
```

It would seem reasonable to me that when the child container resolves IFoo in the FooDecorator constructor, it will try to resolve the parent container's IFoo. But it doesn't. It tries to resolves FooDecorator again, and therefore again and again until a StackOverflow exception is raised.

I know this can be solved by specifying an InjectionConstructor in the child container registration, like this:

```
childContainer.RegisterType<IFoo,FooDecorator>(
   new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<Foo>()));
```

But this seems fragile. If someone wants to change the actual instance of IFoo in the base container from Foo to something else, he would have to also modify all the child containers as well.

So am I missing something? Is there a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use named mapping:

```
parentContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>("decorated");

childContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, FooDecorator>(
   new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IFoo>("decorated")));
```

This way the registration of the decorator depends on the named mapping "decorated" of the interface IFoo.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I'm currently doing, but I don't like this solution very much, since now I have to either manually register every type that uses IFoo, or make sure to register IFoo in every child container, even if it doesn't need to override the default behaviour.

Comment: You could register IFoo in the parent container twice with the same mapping: a named registration and a default one.

Comment: Yep, again a solution I've used, but seems a bit funky. I guess there just isn't any other way now. Thanks

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal childContainer.Resolve<IFoo>() returns an instance of FooDecorator

Answer (score 1):

[onof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696280/1025555) requires fiddling with constructor parameters, that may change during development. [My answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748399/1025555) addresses this but has different drawbacks in exchange.

With my technique the registration would look as follows:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IService, LoggedService<ProfiledService<Service>>>();
```