# How to do open generic decorator chaining with unity + UnityAutoRegistration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, simple-injector

Went off on an interesting tangent today after reading [this article on command handler decoration](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). I wanted to see if I could implement the pattern using Unity instead of [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/), and so far it is proving extremely difficult.

The first thing I had to do was install [UnityAutoRegistration](https://autoregistration.codeplex.com/) to resolve the open generic `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface. Current solution for that aspect is as follows:

```
Container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();

Container.ConfigureAutoRegistration()
    .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
    .Include(type => type.ImplementsOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)),
        (t, c) => c.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), t)
    )
    .ApplyAutoRegistration()
;
```

This works for the first part, resolving any **single** `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`. What's proven frustrating so far is implementing a decoration handler. As soon as I add a second `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` as a decorator, Unity throws a StackOverflowException. I don't know enough about Unity internals, but I'm guessing this is because it can't figure out which instance to resolve to -- the command handler, or the command handler decorator -- since both implement the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interface.

Googling around led me [first to this article](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/GenericDecoratorChainsExampleUnityDependencyInjectionContainer.aspx), which explains how to do it in what I would consider a brute force method. I also found [these](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/11/19/ChainResponsibilityDesignPatternUnityDependencyInjectionContainer.aspx) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109646/how-do-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-with-unity-without-explicitly-specifying-ever) [pages](https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/24015?ProjectName=unity) but none is a complete solution to my problem (and I am too ignorant to figure it out for myself).

I then found [this article, which seems to address my same concerns](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Decorator-Unity-Container-Extension.aspx). However beefy's solution does not account for dealing with open generics. Currently most of our dependencies are loaded from a unity section in the .config file, so I don't want to write a ton of compiled code for each handler or decorator. It seems like having some kind of UnityContainerExtension and DecoratorBuildStrategy is the right way to go, but I can't figure it out.  I have been playing with beefy's code for a little while now, and am completely stuck. My attempts to modify his code to account for generics has led to BadImageFormatExceptions (An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)).

I like the idea of doing this to implement the decorator chaining, because it's short, and there is only 1 line per concern:

```
var container = new Container();

// Go look in all assemblies and register all implementations
// of ICommandHandler<T> by their closed interface:
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with an
// TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

// Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with an
// DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

...but I don't want to change my container from Unity to Simple Injector if I don't have to.

SO my question is how could I go about implementing open generic decorator chaining using unity (plus `UnityAutoRegistration`)?

Answer (score 5):

This would be the equivalent in Unity:

```
// Go look in all assemblies and register all implementa-
// tions of ICommandHandler<T> by their closed interface:
var container = new UnityContainer();

var handlerRegistrations =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from implementation in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where !implementation.IsAbstract
    where !implementation.ContainsGenericParameters
    let services =
        from iface in implementation.GetInterfaces()
        where iface.IsGenericType
        where iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
        select iface
    from service in services
    select new { service, implementation };

foreach (var registration in handlerRegistrations)
{
    container.RegisterType(registration.service, 
        registration.implementation, "Inner1");
}

// Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with an
// TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    "Inner2",
    InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(
        typeof(ICommandHandler<>), "Inner1")));

// Decorate each returned ICommandHandler<T> object with an
// DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<T>.
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<>), 
    InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(
        typeof(ICommandHandler<>), "Inner2")));
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand the problem correctly and I was curious to try and get this to work and I'm by no means an expert on Unity but I was thinking of a solution that is a little easier to implement and would also be easier to do with a different container. It would seem like the only way to support the open generic as well as the other types is to have 2 separate containers (1 for the open generic) and one for your command handlers, this might not be the best way but it worked with Unity and I'm assuming will also be easier with others.

So I came up with this:

I created the containers as follows (you can use your convention approach still im sure for the handler container)

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

var container2 = new UnityContainer();

container2.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<QueryCommand>),
    typeof(QueryCommandHandler));
container.RegisterInstance("Handlers", container2);
container.RegisterInstance(container);
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(DecoratedHandler<>));
```

You see container 2 containing the Handlers as a named instance.

Then I just created a Generic base decorator class as per the requirement of the pattern:

```
public class DecoratorCommandHandler<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private ICommandHandler<TCommand> inner;
    public DecoratorCommandHandler(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public virtual void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
         this.inner.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

Second I created another Generic Handler that would wrap all the Decorations you want to do for your solution, here you will add decorating for TryCatch/Caching/Transactions or whatever else you want to apply to each command handler:

```
public class DecoratedHandler<TCommand>
    : DecoratorCommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    public DecoratedHandler(UnityContainer container)
        : base(BuildInner(container))
    {
    }

    private static ICommandHandler<TCommand> BuildInner(
        UnityContainer container)
    {
         var handlerContainer =
             container.Resolve<UnityContainer>("Handlers");
         var commandHandler =
             handlerContainer.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();

         return new TryCatchCommandHandler<TCommand>(commandHandler);
    }
}
```

You will notice that the first inner resolves the actual command handler as per the one you requested like `QueryCommandHandler`, `UpdateCommandHandler`, `ExecuteCommandHandler` or whatever one dealing with specifics. And then gets wrapped with all the decorators you want common to all of them.

Then I was able to resolve the correct handler, decorated in the correct way:

```
ICommandHandler<QueryCommand> handler =
    container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<QueryCommand>>();

var cmd = new QueryCommand();

handler.Handle(cmd);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I must say I find your solution very creative, so +1 for that. Having multiple containers however, will unfortunately become a big maintenance nightmare. Both containers need to be maintained, and since you're newing up the decorators explicitly, you need to manually inject all dependencies. But more importantly, you will get some very weird behavior with the lifetime of registered services...

Comment: Take for instance the likely situation that both the `TryCatchCommandHandler` and a real command handler depend on an `ILogger` interface, that you registered as singleton. Since the handler and decorator come from a different container, they will both get their own instance, although it is defined as singleton. And this is just an obvious example. It will get really complicated really fast.

Comment: Hi Steven, your observations are again spot on, I agree with the 2 containers being extra maintenance, and I also would recommend that when newing up the decorated handler manually that you use the container to resolve all the dependencies and adhere to their lifetime, Perhaps you can also resolve the TryCatchHandler or whatever other handler from the container rather then to new it up.