# Need help implementing Command Handlers/Bus using Unity DI

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, structuremap, cqrs

Folks,
I am trying to re-factor a legacy brownfield application into a CQRS architecture with commands and a command bus for domain modifications.

The application will more than likely be implemented in Asp.Net MVC3. My employer prefers the use of Unity for DI in MVC applications.

Any examples I can find showing a dependency container for command/bus resolution are based on Structuremap or Autofac, however I will need to use Unity in this implementation. Has anyone used Unity in this manner or know of any examples?

Comment: This will probably be very hard to achieve with Unity. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813630/how-to-do-open-generic-decorator-chaining-with-unity-unityautoregistration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly do you think you need the container at all? Maybe [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/09/19/MessageDispatchingWithoutServiceLocation.aspx) contains some usefull information.

It describes a container agnostic way of handling commmands.

---

**Update**

You mean you would like to have something like this:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
var convention = new CommandHandlerConvention().WithTransaction().WithDeadlockRetry();
builder.Extension<DecoratorExtension>();
builder.Scan(x =>
{
    x.With(convention);
    x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(BarCommand));
});
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(builder);
ICommandHandler<BarCommand> barHandler = container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>("BarHandler");
var command = new BarCommand();
barHandler.Handle(command);
Assert.AreEqual("-->Retry-->Transaction-->BarHandler", command.HandledBy);
```

That registration uses a custom configuration engine for Unity that provides a lot of the features of StructureMap's config.

---

**Update2**

The code samples are part of my [pet project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). The above snippets can be found inside the *TecX.Unity.Configuration.Test* project.

Comment: Although Mark Seemann's article clearly shows how to build an message dispatching architecture, shows how to prevent the Service Locator anti-pattern, is by itself very interesting, and shows this without using a container, this will probably not help the OP. It is almost impossible to keep the composition root maintainable without a container, when working on an application that is designed around generic interfaces such as `ICommandHandler<T>` and `IEventHandler<T>`. The manual wiring is simply too painful. So the OPs question remains: how to do this with Unity?

Comment: @Sebastian I am looking for a simple and manageable way to wire up commands and command handlers. A simple synchronous bus would probably be a way to go but the implementations I have seen such as NServiceBus are overkill my needs.

Comment: @Steven Please see my update. Btw.: what's the meaning of OP?

Comment: OP means something like 'original poster', or is at least refering to the person asking the question. I don't know where this comes from, but this abbreviation is used a lot here at SO, Stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Are `ConfigurationBuilder`,  `CommandHandlerConvention`, and `DecoratorExtension` part of Unity? If not, where are they from?

Comment: @Steven They are from my [pet project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). It contains a rather large set of extensions for Unity. The above code snippets can be found inside the _TecX.Unity.Configuration.Test_ project.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: Can you add that link to your answer?