# Selecting an IoC framework (for DI and AOP)

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, aop

We are building a .NET application and i'd like to integrate a framework for doing DI and some AOP (injecting some diagnostics/logging code).

I know there's a multitude of frameworks out there, i am not sure which one to select, since each site that reviews them gives out different results and opinions.

I would love to hear some objective information based on real world experience for doing the things we require (listed above).

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/143302)

Comment: Read my Dependency Injection / IoC article (which also demonstrates my container): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386164/Get-injected-into-the-world-of-inverted-dependenci

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Take a look at PRISM, UNITY and MEF to stay fully in the realm of Microsoft patterns and (best) practices. No reason to divert from that imo, unless you do really small projects (for which Prism may be oversized).

Comment: +1 for Unity. It's easy to learn, lightweight and has builtin AOP support.

Comment: Unfortunately [generic decorator support with Unity is very poor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813630/how-to-do-open-generic-decorator-chaining-with-unity-unityautoregistration), and with MEF it is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is foremost in the design of your application. If you design your application around the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, adding cross-cutting concerns will mostly be as simple as writing a decorator. In other words, when you need code weaving frameworks as Postsharp or need to do interception, you probably need to take a close look at your design again. Take a look for instance at how to model business operations with [commands and handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91), or how to model queries as [DTOs and handlers](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

All containers allow you to wrap services with decorators, simply because you could register a lambda that does something like this:

```cs
container.Register<ICommandHandler<ProcessOrderCmd>>(() =>
    new DiagnosticsCommandHandlerDecorator<ProcessOrderCmd>(
        new ProcessOrderCommandHandler()));
```

However, when the whole application is designed around SOLID and the application grows big, manually configuring every service like this will become cumbersome and time consuming. So in that case it is very useful to pick a DI framework contains a batch registration feature and has support for registering decorators. Especially support for handling generic decorators (as the `DiagnosticsCommandHandler<T>` as shown above) will get important.

For instance, when you use the [Simple Injector IoC container](https://simpleinjector.org) you can register all command handlers with a decorator in just two lines of code:

```cs
// This registers all command handlers in the container.
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);

// This wraps all command handlers with the given decorator.
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(DiagnosticsCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Although some patterns or frameworks might be overkill for small applications, I believe that the SOLID principles are core principles for object oriented design, and every application should be design with those principles in mind.

Comment: My need for the decorators is mostly for diagnostic purposes (i.e: log all method parameters for testing). I am planning to inject this code to most if not all of the methods in the core layer of our application for the testing period (PostSharp allows injecting this at the assembly level i believe, for example).

Comment: My experience is that those decorators can be used to plug in many features. It is hard to predict what for decorators you need in the future, but the nice thing is that this doesn't matter, because the design is very flexible/pluggable and allows you to add what you need, without having complicated design with a lot of YAGNI code.

Comment: And don't forget that unless you use [the commercial version of PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/purchase), the only way to add cross-cutting concerns is by applying attributes to your code. This can still result in maintenance problems, since you still need to apply that attribute everywhere and change all those lines when you need to add/change/remove cross-cutting concerns. This is a violation of the Open/closed principle. Good design comes first; tools second.