# Resolve multiple implementation of a single interface in unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-interception

I have the following scenario :

```
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IFoo3 { }

public class Foo4 : IFoo3 { }

public class Foo1 : IFoo { }

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{  
    Foo2 (IFoo object1, IFoo3 object2)   
}
```

on the client side :

```
  IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("Foo1");
  container.RegisterType<IFoo3, Foo4>();
  container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>("Foo2");

  IFoo3 obj = container.Resolve<IFoo3>(); //Resolve 1

  IFoo obj2 = container.Resolve<IFoo>(); //Resolve 2
```

The resolve 2 (see comment ) gives an error that a constructor could not be found.

I basically want it to resolve to Foo2 class. I even tried using parameteroverrides but that did not work either.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Your `Foo2` is a decorator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the Decorator Pattern with Unity without explicitly specifying every parameter in the InjectionConstructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109646/how-do-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-with-unity-without-explicitly-specifying-ever)

Comment: See: http://www.beefycode.com/post/Decorator-Unity-Container-Extension.aspx

Comment: Thanks a ton steven....the beefycode blog was of immense help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Resolve` with no parameters gets you an instance of the *unnamed* registration (no *named* registrations).

Calling `ResolveAll` with no parameters gets you instances of all *named* registrations (does not include the *unnamed* registration).

You have no *unnamed* registration of `IFoo`.