# Unity: Specify instance for single constructor parameter and auto-resolve remaining parameter types?

Tags: constructor, unity-container

I have an interface `INexus` that is used in two different classes. The first class `Nexus` is the core functionality, the other is a "decorating class" `NexusDecorator` that takes in a `INexus` parameter, calls it, and adds further value to the result.

```
public interface INexus
{
    string Eval();
}

public class Nexus : INexus
{
    public string Eval()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

public class NexusDecorator : INexus
{
    private readonly INexus _nexus;
    private readonly IClock _clock;
    private readonly IPrettifyer _prettifyer;

    public NexusDecorator(INexus nexus, IClock clock, IPrettifyer prettifyer)
    {
        _nexus = nexus;
        _clock = clock;
        _prettifyer = prettifyer;
    }

    public string Eval()
    {
        var s = _clock.Now() + ": " + _nexus.Eval();
        return _prettifyer.Emphasize(s); // returns somehing like "<i>12:30: Hello World!</i>"
    }
}
```

I use Unity to register the types:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<INexus, Nexus>("base")

container.RegisterType<INexus, NexusDecorator>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<INexus>("base"),
        new ResolvedParameter<IClock>(),
        new ResolvedParameter<IPrettifyer>()
        ));
```

The `InjectionConstructor` is set up with a list of instances that matches the constructor of `NexusDecorator`in the right sequence, using registered types. This is great, but the only exception to the default registrations is the use of the named `INexus` registration that targets the `Nexus` class. It seems overly cumbersome having to specify how Unity should resolve what is essentially default registrations of `IClock`and `IPrettifyer`.

Is there a way to tell Unity to *only* override the `INexus`parameter of the constructor and ommit specification of the remaining parameters?

-Sigurd Garshol

Comment: does the answer for question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109646/how-do-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-with-unity-without-explicitly-specifying-ever look acceptable ?

Comment: That is pretty much the same question as mine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tsimbalar points out, this question has been asked before:

[How do I use the Decorator Pattern with Unity without explicitly specifying every parameter in the InjectionConstructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109646/how-do-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-with-unity-without-explicitly-specifying-ever)

It seems the short answer is: "You don't". It appears that Unity is able to automatically resolve construction of classes with only a single constructor, but once you start specifying individual parameters you're stuck with specifying them all.

In the linked answer the OP concedes that, in his case, using InjectionFactory to explicitly `new` up the object graph is more readable and enables him to catch up with constructor parameter extension at compile-time.

The down-side would appear to be that you would perhaps need to maintain a large object graph, but really: Each of the objects that are created using `new` could be *resolved* insetad if desired.